# Reading string over args

Tags: c

**Hi,**

I am trying to read a string into my code via the args[]-parameter, like I would do in Java.
So basically, this is what I want to do:

```
 - read the String "machine" over launch-parameter
 - go through every letter of that string in a loop
 - while in the loop, check is current letter equals "e"
 - if letter equals "e", replace it with "a"
 - return edited string
```

This is the best way to phrase my elemental questions to C. So I'd be happy if you won't take this post offensive.

How could I implement that code?

Comment: Please, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that (almost) doesn't involve pointers, though you should really learn about pointers if you're going to do even moderately advanced C programming.

```
void replace_e_with_a(char str[])
{
    int i, len = strlen(str);
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (str[i] == e) str[i] = a;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
     replace_e_with_a(argv[i]);
     puts(argv[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void replace_e_with_a(char * str)
{
    int i;
    if (NULL != str)
      while ('\0' != *str ) {
          if (*str == 'e')
              *str = 'a';
          ++str;
      }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
     replace_e_with_a(argv[i]);
     puts(argv[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `*` do in this code? That's something I never saw in programming until now.

Comment: Sure, this is called the pointer dereference operator, and you can get a good explanation [there](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/). There's an equivalent operator in Pascal (or Delphi) : the `^` postfix operator.

Comment: Don't you mean (while(*str))?  You will never hit memory address 0x0 by incrementing str, but you want to stop when you hit a `'\0'`.

Comment: Well, I see what the pointer basically does, but I don't get why you used a pointer at `(char * str)`. Why would'nt `char[] str` work?

Comment: In plain C, `char ptr[]` and `char *ptr` are the same thing type-wise. the `ptr[offset]` notation is converted to `*(ptr + offset)` under the hood. Be wary that `char[] ptr` is a java notation, it doesn't work in C.